# How to attach a new div to my jquery code?

Tags: jquery

I have a slideshow, its only changing photos. Now I need to add a new different div box on top of each photo. At the moment jquery code takes just #slideshow and .active. How to amend it to grab also new different ".newbox" (.newbox1 for first photo, .newbox2 for second and so on). This is my photo slideshow jquery code:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');

    // use this to pull the divs in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow DIV:first');

    // uncomment below to pull the divs randomly
    // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});

</script>
```

My html:

```
div id="slideshow">
   <div class="active">
        <a href="http://www.mylink.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://route/img.jpg" alt="alt" /></a>

    <div class="newbox"><h4><a href="/href">WTF?!</a></h4><p>something</p><a class="bttn action" href="/shop/what-the-at-taz">Buy Now</a> <a class="bttn" href="/shop/explore?designer=211">See More</a></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$active.children('.newbox').text('write your text here');`

Comment: what do you mean by write your text here? I want to enter the text through html, and where is the best place to put this line of code?

Comment: if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');
$active.children('.newbox').text('<p>Description</p>');

In <div class="newbox"></div> will become <div class="newbox"><p>Description1</p></div>

Comment: Robert, its not about description because I will have not only description, but also titles and buttons. One thing what I need is to add changable newbox1, newbox2, newbox3...

Comment: After the image was changed to another do you still want the <div class="newbox"> content to appear for the precedence image?

Comment: If you want only to display details about the active image you could pass an array as param for function slideSwitch which should contain the details about the image something like data['title'], data['price']. And use something like $('<h2>'data['title']'</h2>').appendTo('.newbox'); This will create <div class="newbox"><h2>Product title</h2></div>. If you want to use different newbox for each image then you could name the class newbox_imageName.